# A fast and accurate method for comparing similarity between text documents

Tags: performance, algorithm, similarity, tf-idf

I need to compare two groups of documents (e.g. one group might have 1000 documents) and determine which document of the second group is the most similar to the certain document in the first group. Thus far, I used TF/IDF and cosine similarity but I need something more faster and accurate like TF/IDF :) Can you suggest me some faster algorithm or improvement of TF/IDF time?

Comment: Do you want to gain precision or speed ? Do you have use an index to store the intermediate TFxIDF ? Do you want to use NLP technics ? Synonymes ?

Comment: How do you define **"similar"**. A fast first step may be n-gram historgram compare. or compare the sets of words used in the documents.

Comment: Mr K, speed is the most important, and then also accurate result :)

Comment: MrSmith42, 'similar' I mean if you have e.g. (large documents I mean, not a sentence) doc1="cat is an animal" doc2="dog is an animal" doc1'="cat is an animal. cat likes to eat mouses" doc2'="dog is an animal. dogs like people" similarity(doc1, doc1') = 0.7, similarity(doc1, doc2') = 0.3,similarity(doc2, doc1') = 0.25,similarity(doc2, doc2') = 0.7

Comment: MrSmith42, do you mean first to compare documents with n-gram similarity and then perform tf/idf on the group of similar documents...I think this will speed up tf/idf because the smaller corpus of words will be just in the group of documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what type of differences you are trying to match. The fastest approach I know of is use shingle matching with minHash: http://www.stanford.edu/~ashishg/amdm/handouts/scribed-lec10.pdf 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash

It is used to find near/exact duplicates, not partially similar documents.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look on this method. For me it's the most important to find two documents with the most similar text

Comment: Hi,I understand now, this method is the best only for duplicates not for example 2 text documents that have similarity of 0.5 (1-equal, 0-totally diferent). Am I right? I don't need the method like this, but thanks anyway